# How to render a component C1 when a value is set from component C2 using a service S1

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, rerender, angular17, angular-component-life-cycle

[check this image for visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNxTB.png)

I am using Angular v17.

I am fetching products information using APIs. The products are fetched in the product-list-component using the fetch-all-products-service. Then I am checking if the value of 'category' is set in the filter-form-service. If so, then the component is using the API that fetches all products but if 'category' exists then filter the products of that category.

When the form in filter-form-template is submitted, the value of 'category' is set using the setCategoryValue() method of filter-form-service.

Now, I want to render the product-list-component each time the form is submitted. how to do this?

*See the image for clear visualization